# Обращение к базе данных из класса

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет!
Подскажите такой момент.
На сколько плохой практикой является передавать как параметр $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)  в класс.

Что я хочу сделать. Пользователь вводит данные, я должен проверить наличие этих данных в базе, если есть то вернуть другой столбец, соответствующий этим данным. Если нет, то провести операции с этими данными и внести данные в базу.

Что я делаю схематично:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(...)
class A {
  public function __construct($data, $link) {
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->link = $link;
  public function B() {$result = mysqli_query( $this->links , $query)}
}
$Object = new A($data, $link);
$Object->B();
```

В общем код не правильный, но это просто схема, думаю смысл понятен. У меня все работает. Но на сколько такой подход не правильный?

Comment: я не совсем приверженец такого подхода. Для меня: подключение к БД и работа (даже для подключение и прочих сетапов) - это должен быть отдельный класс, не просто `$link = mysqli_connect(...)`, а целый, отдельный, самостоятельный класс. А если вам нужен будет линк для `$this->links`, то вы просто обращаетесь к переменной класса(функции), а она возвращает вам линк, который создавался в конструкторе класса (тобишь ваш `$link = mysqli_connect(...)`).

Answer (score 1):

Тоже, так, очень схематично (solid. начало):

```
class MysqlConn
{
    __construct($host, $my_user, $password, $db)
    // тут открываете соединение с бд
}

class Crud
{
    __construct(MysqlConn $dbConn)
    // тут запросы в бд
 }

class UserData 
{
    __construct(Crud $db)
    // тут операции с пользовательскими данными
    // и передача подготовленных данных объекту класса Crud
}

$mysqlConn = new MysqlConn($host, $my_user, $password, $db);
$crud = new Crud($mysqlConn);
$userData = new UserData($crud);

// ... somewhere in a code far far away
$userData->crud->saveInput($data);
```

Т.е. в данном случае мы разделили ответственности между классами, разнесли свойства и методы, решающие принципиально разные задачи, по отдельным классам. В дальнейшем нам не надо будет снова повторять реализацию подключения/работы с бд в других классах, достаточно будет просто вызывать существующие реализации. Далее, мы избавились от зависимости класса-обработчика на пользовательские данные. Получили гибкость - не придётся постоянно создавать новый объект под новую порцию данных.

Comment: Если уж пускаться в такие тонкости, то независимый от UserData класс Crud - не очень хорошая идея. Он будет неминуемо пропускать SQL инъекцию. Лучше все-таки делать под каждую сущность свой дата маппер, в котором явно прописывать имена таблиц и полей

Comment: А в этой схеме вообще непонятно, зачем нужен класс UserData и почему нельзя просто сделать` $crud->saveInput($data);`

Comment: Данные перед отправкой как минимум надо валидировать. Тогда на класс крад будет возложена ответственность, логически не связанная с его прямой обязанностью. В данном случае реализуется примитивнейший mvc, UserData ака контроллер, Crud ака модель.

Comment: Из вашей схемы, извините, этого ничего не видно. У вас тупо вызывается метод класса crud, и непонятно, почему нельзя вызвать его отдельно. Упрощать код для объяснения полезно, но важно не перейти при этом тонкую грань, когда упрощенный код становится непригодным к использованию. Код автора, при всей его примитивности, вполне работоскособный, а ваш, даже если реализовать отсутствующие методы - нет.

Comment: Кстати, MVC же ваш пример не имеет вообще никакого отношения. Все что вы тут написали - это только модель.

Comment: Благодарю за ваши замечания, я обязательно их обдумаю.

Comment: :) Но в в принципе я, разумеется, поддерживаю такое разделение.

Answer (score 0):

Это единственно правильный подход.